# Transit through France with Switzerland visa

Tags: transit, france, switzerland

I have a multiple entry visa for Switzerland, but I will go to Switzerland via France. Is it possible that I can transit through France to Switzerland?

Comment: Is your multiple entry visa a Schengen (États Schengen or similar) visa, or a Swiss national visa? Can you detail exactly what it says?

Answer (score 1):

Unless your visa states that it is for Switzerland only, you can travel through other Schengen countries after your first use of the visa.

As a rule, you can also transit through other Schengen countries on the first use of your visa, as long as your main visit is to the country that supplied your visa.